# Как через requests отправить удалённый внешний файл указав имя файла/его тип?

Tags: python, urllib, requests

Есть картинка:

```
jpg = "http://site1.ru/image.jpg"
```

как при помощи `requests.post(url, files=...)` отправить её на сайт не загружая предварительно локально?
Если отправлять таким образом:

```
requests.post(url, files={'file': urllib2.urlopen(jpg).read()})
```

, то она отправляется без имени файла (`file=file`) и сервер её не принимает.

Comment: вы можете явно указать имя и content-type  например так: files = {'file': ('myfile.jpg', urllib2.urlopen(jpg).read(), 'image/jpg')}. Вы уверены, что проблема именно в этом? Как вы определили, что "сервер её не принимает"?

Comment: Благодарю, это как раз то, что было нужно! А определил, что сервер не принимает очень просто, в ответ приходит "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека requests позволяет более гибко работать с передачей файлов с помощью кортежа (filename, data, mimetype). В вопросе код измениться на:

```
files = {'file': ('myfile.jpg', urllib2.urlopen(jpg).read(), 'image/jpg')}
```

Так же requests можно использовать например для передачи нескольких файлов через форму "multiple file field" например так:

```
multiple_files = [
        ('files', ('myfile1.jpg', urllib2.urlopen(jpg1).read(), 'image/jpeg')),
        ('files', ('myfile2.jpg', urllib2.urlopen(jpg2).read(), 'image/jpeg'))]
requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
```

Подробнее [тут](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) и [тут](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

Обратите внимание, что urllib2.urlopen(jpg).read() [создаёт файлоподобный объект](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls), поэтому так или иначе используя .read() вы всё же загружаете данные локально, хоть и не пишите их в файловую систему.